# SOAPUI: Read http log with groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

is there any way to read http log for specific test step?

In my http log there are several response-requests messages for current test step.

The following code gives me only first request/last response, but I need to take value from
second response.

```
log.info context.expand('${getHashValue#Request}')
log.info context.expand('${getHashValue#Response}')
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPD:**
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your questions, what do you mean for "several response-request message for current test step", do you run several times a TestCase where is you TestStep located? Your testCase has only one testStep and one groovy step? Can you provide more details about your test?

Comment: My testcase has one testStep with POST request.
During this request execution there are several redirects, which are visible in http log.
My purpose is to get value from one of this redirects header.
But in `log.info context.expand('${getHashValue#Response}')` I can see only the latest response.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can get any kind of soap ui logs

```
def logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor.getLogArea( "http log" )
```

//error log can be replaced with jetty log, script log, SoapUI log, error log,memory log, wsrm log

```
if( logArea !=null )
{
  def model = logArea.model
  if( model.size > 0 )            
     for( c in 0..(model.size-1) )         
      {
        def value= model.getElementAt(c).toString()
        if(value.contains("ETag")) // here you can mention if you want to extract anything particular from the logs
        {
        log.info  "value = " + value
        }
      }
}
```

this code can be even little modified to save soap ui logs in a file

credits :- https://webservice-testing.blogspot.in/2012/04/capture-soapui-logs-to-file.html